# Insert data into PostgreSQL table with a T-SQL script

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

```
INSERT [dbo].[ProductPrice] ([Id], [CreatedDate], [ProductId], [ProductType], [ItemPrice]) 
VALUES (N'45bf8262-cc13-480e-b85a-0015860071aa', 
        CAST(N'2017-04-04 12:18:29.993' AS DateTime), 
        N'bb08c494-6f1e-4410-ac02-4c90ef46ef6a', 2, 
        CAST(600.0000 AS Decimal(18, 4)))

INSERT [dbo].[Rule] ([Id], [CreatedDate], [ProductType], [Condition], [Calculation], [Hrid]) 
VALUES (N'1c3af075-449f-4db9-bd46-06de73a60a84', 
        CAST(N'2017-07-20 10:51:00.910' AS DateTime), 
        2, N'HasTenDiscount', N'0.9*[InitialPrice]', N'ten-discount')
```

How to insert data?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking here? How do you insert data into the table?

Comment: What is wrong what you have here? It is i not very clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, how convert that script?

Comment: Convert your syntax from SQL server compatible to PostgreSQL compatible format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. replace square brackets around identifiers with double quotes
2. replace `DateTime` data type with `timestamp` one
3. replace `N` before string with `E`, or just remove it
4. rewrite expressions, like `N'0.9*[InitialPrice]'` according to rules above, but keep in mind that procedures that were using such expressions will need "translation" as well
5. add `INTO` after `INSERT` statement

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html